# exit program when all goroutines finish

Tags: go, goroutine

I have two go routine functions, one creates data and one adds the data to the database. When I'm done creating data I want to finish adding data but I don't know how many times I'm going to call the function.

```
for {
  select {
  case c <- dataChan:
    go func() {
      if data == false {
        return // keeps the program running but never exits
      }
      createData(c.Data) // sends data to dataChan until data == false 
    }
    go func() {
      addData(c.Data) // need to keep the program running until all these goroutines finish
    }
  }
}
```

`createData()` creates and sends data to the `dataChan` and based on some variables it will eventually set `data` to `false` and cause the program to be held open by returning over and over again and stops creating more data, but I feel like there should be a cleaner way that allows me to exit when all the `addData()` goroutines finish. I have seen people use a channel for this but I don't know exactly how many times I'm going to call the function.

**UPDATE: WORKING CODE**

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for {
  select {
  case c <- dataChan:
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
      if data == false {
        wg.Wait()
        os.Exit(0)
      }
      createData(c.Data)
    }
    go func() {
      addData(c.Data)
      defer wg.Done()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) is what you want here. You `wg.Add(1)` before starting each goroutine (or `wg.Add(n)` if you know the count up front), `wg.Done()` in each routine when finished, and  `wg.Wait()` in `main` to wait untill all finish. The linked docs have an example, and as the docs note, copying it won't do what you want; you may want to make the variable a pointer (`wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)`).